# Cannot add tensor to the batch: number of elements does not match. Shapes are: [tensor]: [1], [batch]: [2]

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision, data-science

Working on VQA problem,  Train and Validation Dataset is in Urdu Language, contains three columns, i.e., Path, Question, and Answer.
In this problem, I will explain all the steps that I have used:

1. Load the Dataset both training and validation
2. Cleaned both datasets
3. Created Both Datasets Questions and Answers attribute word tokens and stored all the unique words of both datasets in a single empty vocabulary set, vocab_set.
4. Used an encoder to encode each word as a number as follows: encoder = tfds.deprecated.text.TokenTextEncoder(vocab_set) whereas the length of vocab_set is 354
5. Similarly, for creating the data pipeline for both datasets (train and validation), I have defined three functions named as "encode_fn, preprocess and create_pipeline" and also globally defined BATCH_SIZE=8 and IMG_SIZE=(200,200)
6. After these steps, I have created the training and validation Dataset objects as follows:
   train_dataset=create_pipeline(train_dataframe)
   validation_dataset=create_pipeline(val_dataframe)
7. Created a TensorFlow dataset (raw_df) from tensors in train_dataframe, containing paths and questions as one component and answers as another component.
8. Then define a hybrid model with a CNN for image processing (MobileNetV2) and an RNN for text processing (LSTMs). The models are combined and trained for tasks involving both images and text data.

When running this step, the error was raised as follows:

InvalidArgumentError: Graph execution error:
Node: 'IteratorGetNext'
Cannot add tensor to the batch: number of elements does not match. Shapes are: [tensor]: [1], [batch]: [2]
[[{{node IteratorGetNext}}]] [Op:__inference_train_function_6253606]

Moreover, I have tried to inspect the issue. So when throwly reviewed the preprocess function the question area is perfectly fine but whereas the answer part was making problem like there are some tensors that contain only 1 element and some of them contain 2 elements like dimension 1 and 2. So how could I handle this inside this function:
#Function to load and decode the image from the file paths in the dataframe and use the encoder function

```
BATCH_SIZE=16
IMG_SIZE=(200,200)


#Function that uses the encoder created to encode the input question and answer string
def encode_fn(text):
    return np.array(encoder.encode(text.numpy()))

def preprocess(ip, ans):
    img, ques = ip  # ip is a list containing image paths and 
   questions
    
    img = tf.io.read_file(img)
    img = tf.image.decode_jpeg(img, channels=3)
    img = tf.image.resize(img, IMG_SIZE)
    img = tf.math.divide(img, 255)  # The image has been loaded, decoded, and resized 
    
    # The question string is converted to encoded list with a fixed size of 50 with padding with 0 value
    ques = tf.py_function(encode_fn, inp=[ques], Tout=tf.int32)
    paddings = [[0, 50 - tf.shape(ques)[0]]]
    ques = tf.pad(ques, paddings, 'CONSTANT', constant_values=0)
    ques.set_shape([50])  # Explicit shape must be defined in order to create the Input pipeline
    
    #The Answer is also encoded 
    ans=tf.py_function(encode_fn,inp=[ans],Tout=tf.int32)
    ans.set_shape([1])
    
    return (img,ques),ans

def create_pipeline(dataframe):
    raw_df=tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(((dataframe['Path'],dataframe['Question']),dataframe['Answer']))
    df=raw_df.map(preprocess)#Preprocessing function is applied to the dataset
    df=df.batch(BATCH_SIZE)#The dataset is batched
    return df

#The training and validation Dataset objects are created
train_dataset=create_pipeline(train_dataframe)
validation_dataset=create_pipeline(val_dataframe)

raw_df = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(((train_dataframe['Path'], train_dataframe['Question']), train_dataframe['Answer']))


And the model architecture is as follows:

#Creating the CNN model for image processing


CNN_Input=tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(200,200,3),name='image_input')

mobilenetv2=tf.keras.applications.mobilenet_v2.MobileNetV2(input_shape=(200,200,3), alpha=1.0, include_top=False,
                                                      weights='imagenet', input_tensor=CNN_Input)

CNN_model=tf.keras.models.Sequential()
CNN_model.add(CNN_Input)
CNN_model.add(mobilenetv2)
CNN_model.add(tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D())






#Creating the RNN model for text processing
RNN_model=tf.keras.models.Sequential()
RNN_Input=tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(50),name='text_input')
RNN_model.add(RNN_Input)
RNN_model.add(tf.keras.layers.Embedding (len(vocab_set)+1,256))
RNN_model.add(tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(256,stateful=False,return_sequences=True,recurrent_initializer='glorot_uniform')))
RNN_model.add(tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(256,stateful=False,return_sequences=True,recurrent_initializer='glorot_uniform')))
RNN_model.add(tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(512,stateful=False,return_sequences=False,recurrent_initializer='glorot_uniform')))


concat=tf.keras.layers.concatenate([CNN_model.output,RNN_model.output])
dense_out=tf.keras.layers.Dense(len(vocab_set),activation='softmax',name='output')(concat)

model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[CNN_Input,RNN_Input],
                    outputs=dense_out)
model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy()])
model.summary()
```